# Need guide on HOW TO make development in VirtualBox Ubuntu and debug with an emulator on a Windows Host

Tags: android, android-emulator, tizen

I have a development Ubuntu OS running on a VirtualBox on Windows 7 host. I tried to start development of Tizen app, but emulator response extremely slow on the Ubuntu Virtual Machine. I have searched online for tutorial on how to make a connection from a host Development environment to an emulator running on a VirtualBox.

This is my setup:

Host OS: Win 7 with emulator
Guest OS in virtualbox: Ubuntu 12.04 with IDE

Is there any tutorial on how to connect them in one development environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found how perfom such debugging:

1. Run IDE on guest OS (in my case, it is Ubuntu) and virtual device on
   host OS (in my case, it is Windows).
2. Open command line and use
       command  sdb connect 10.0.2.2:26101 (26101 is a default port of emulator)
3. That it. In IDE in list of
           devices you shoould see new device with such IP and port. Now just
           use it to run and ddebug application.

If you want to make debug visa versa (run emulator on guest OS and access it from host OS), just use IP 10.0.2.15:26101.